# How do I put HTML, JS and CSS in a Github page .md file?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I'm writing a post for my Github-hosted site. I'm writing to `my-first-post.md`.

I have Javascript in `script` tags, CSS in `style` tags, and HTML in `div`s and `span`s.

When I paste the code in the `.md` and run `jekyll serve` thru Ruby, all I get is a page with the raw HTML.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"HTML is a publishing format; Markdown is a writing format." --[daringfireball](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#philosophy)

Markdown is supposed to be simple.

You shouldn't be putting javascript into markdown unless you have a good reason to be doing so and even then I don't think every markdown converter will process javascript.

Ideally, your markdown should be confined to [this list](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) and maybe some simple HTML.

Any CSS or javascript should be included as part of your *theme*.

Edit, explaining jekyll filestructure:

So your Jekyll site should have a file structure that looks something like [this](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/). In very broad terms, your CSS and javascript should be in the `default.html` file located in the `_layouts` folder. You'll probably notice that the file appears to be a regular HTML file, more or less. The blog post--which is the markdown after it has been converted to HTML--will insert itself into the layout at the `{{ content }}` tag.

Also, the CSS and javascript doesn't have to be *in* `default.html`. It can also be in external files that you *link* to from `default.html`

Comment: So if I want to include JS, CSS and custom HTML in just one post, I'd need to `include` an HTML/JS/CSS file?

Comment: If I understand the question, I think your answer might be found in the `_includes` folder. Have a look at [this link](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/)  again.

I will say that Jekyll isn't going to be particularly good at loading javascript and CSS into just one page. You'll probably need to create a layout just for that page. 

I might not be understanding everything though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MDX](https://mdxjs.com/). It can do a lot. But if you want to use something more appropriate for the task at hand, I'd suggest looking into [Astro](https://astro.build/) . You can find more on these websites. For astro you can install the CLI and write markdown in less than 2 minutes. And also, it's very fast and integrates with a lot of frameworks.